# Power law tail constant

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I know that the CDF $F(x)$ of a positive integer-valued random variable satisfies:
$$ 1-F(x) \sim \frac{C}{x^\alpha \Gamma(1-\alpha)} $$
where $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Then is $C>1$ necessarily? Doing an integral on the continuous density $f(x) \propto 1/x^{1.5}$ suggests that this is true, but I'm not sure in general whether it makes sense at all.

Comment: Didn't you ask about the condition $C>1$? How does the accepted answer address this condition?

Comment: @Did my apologies, you're right. I skimmed the answer way too quickly and misinterpreted it as "conclude $1>C>0$." Thanks.

Comment: @Bey "I tried to show why C>1 is not necessary" Where did you do that?

Comment: @Bey Indeed C can be anything positive--but you do not prove it.

Comment: @hbp "it is very likely" What? That C>1? Hmmm... no.

Comment: @Bey "clearly shows" No. To be unable to unearth an objection to some result does not prove the result holds.

Comment: @Bey The question is to determine if every $C>0$ such that $1-F(x)\sim C/(x^\alpha\Gamma(1-\alpha))$ for some CDF $F$ is actually $>1$ or not. You stated that you were unable to deduce $C>1$ from $1-F(x)\sim C/(x^\alpha\Gamma(1-\alpha))$, this does not answer the question.

Comment: @Did Rather, I am stating the obvious that to be unable to prove something is not a proof that this something is wrong. In the present case, it happens that every C>0 can indeed appear in the equivalent of 1-F, but, so far, you did not produce a proof of this. (Since you forced me to repeat this trivium already several times, I will stop here.)

Comment: @hbp "the exceptions are relatively rare" Not at all. One can realize every C>0 for every alpha in (0,1). Please see my comment on Bey's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $1-F(x) \sim \frac{C}{x^\alpha \Gamma(1-\alpha)}$ here means

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1-F(x)}{\frac{C}{x^\alpha \Gamma(1-\alpha)}} = 1$$

Since $0\leq 1-F(x) \leq 1$, and  $x>0,\;\Gamma(1-\alpha)>0$, we can rearrange to get:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (1-F(x))x^\alpha \Gamma(1-\alpha) = C$$

However, $C$ can be any positive value, so it is not necessary that $C>1$

---

Here is a specific [counterexample](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20x%20approaches%20infinity%20of%200.5*%281%2F%28x%5E%280.5%29%29%2B1%2F%28x%5E1%29%29*%28%28x%5E%280.5%29%29*Gamma%280.5%29%29):

$$1-F(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right), x\in \mathbb{N}$$

This corresponds to the [monotonically decreasing pmf](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20of%20%281-0.5*%281%2F%28x%5E%280.5%29%29%2B1%2F%28x%5E1%29%29%29%20)

$$ f(x)=\frac{0.25\sqrt{x}+0.5}{x^2}, x\in \mathbb{N}$$

Calculating our limit with $\alpha=0.5$ we get:

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)\sqrt{x}\Gamma(0.5) = 0.886227 < 1 $$

Therefore, with $C=0.886227$ we get our [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20as%20x%20approaches%20infinity%20of%200.5*%281%2F%28x%5E%280.5%29%29%2B1%2F%28x%5E1%29%29%2F%28.886227%2F%28%28x%5E%280.5%29%29*Gamma%280.5%29%29%29):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{0.886227}{\sqrt{x}\Gamma(0.5)}}= 1 \implies \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{x}\right) \sim \frac{0.886227}{x^{0.5} \Gamma(1-0.5)}$$

Comment: @gogurt I've added a specific counterexample to this post.

Comment: Much simpler: changing F on a bounded subset allows to tune the value of C at will while leaving the asymptotics of 1-F unchanged.

Comment: @Did: that's a great point. thanks.